# Error while importing data tier application

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

When i'm trying to import a bacpac file which was taken from a 2016 version SQL SERVER instance to a SQL SERVER 2014 instance throwing out an error as follows

```
**Could not import package.
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'xxx'.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [xxx]
    WITH IDENTITY = N'xxxsa';
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [xxx]
    WITH IDENTITY = N'xxxsa';
 (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)**
```

The compatibility of db is already been set to 2014 before import and trying with import data tier application method.

Comment: Can you put your full script in here please?

Comment: @connorg98. you mean exact error ??

Comment: Yes please it may help

Comment: it's the same as i have mentioned above in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just dropped the scoped credential and it worked fine.

**`DROP DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [xxx]`**

Comment: Mark your reply as answer.